# Terminal size to connector size

Tags: connector, wire-terminals

This may be a stupid question, so please bear with me.

I have a fuse block with #8-32 and #10-32 screw terminals. What size loop connectors would I order for those, for proper fit? The loop connectors are usually listed in fractions of inch. How do you convert #8 and #10 to loop connector sizes?

Comment: [Here you go, buddy.](http://www.engineersedge.com/screw_threads_chart.htm) This gives you the defined min and max sizes, in inches, of standard ANSI screws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search term you need is "tap drill sizes". Look for clearance drill sizes in a table.

There will usually be close fit and free fit sizes, which will give you a range of sizes for the ID of your ring terminal.

#8 might be  0.1695/0.1770"

#10 might be 0.1960/0.2010"

Comment: Thank you. So looking at the #10 for example, would come out to a #9 drill, and the closest connector size to a #9 drill size would be 13/64 or thereabouts (rounded up). Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, that should be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about crimp terminals, the ring terminals I've used are specified in terms of screw size, so you want terminals to fit #8 and #10 screws (two different sizes).

They also accept different wire size ranges.  Terminals with yellow insulation are for #10 or #12 wire, blue for #14 and #16, and red for #18 - 22.

So, if you are using #14 wire, and want to terminate it on a #8-32 screw, you need a blue ring terminal for #8 screw.

Comment: Is there a chart of the colors? My #10 terminals will receive 4 gauge, while the #8 will receive less, maybe 12 or 14 gauge.

Comment: The common wire size vs insulation colour coding is as I listed. Lugs for wire larger than #10 are usually uninsulated, and often have the wire size marked.  I don't think I'd like to put a #4 wire on a #10 screw - I'd prefer to use a 1/4" or larger bolt.

Answer (score 1):

Take the number of the screw (#10, for example), multiply it by 13, and add 60 to the result. This will give you the diameter of the screw in thousandths of an inch.
Example: #10 screw: 10 x 13 = 130 + 60 = 190, therefore the diameter of the screw is .190", or slightly over 3/16".